# Emit on first emit of second observable after first observable emits

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I have 2 Observables, `a` and `b`. I want to combine them like so:

```
a: ---x---------x-------x------|
b: ------x-x-x----x-x-x---x-x--|

o: ------x--------x-------x----|
```

That is, I want the result Observable to emit on the first emission of `b` that comes directly after an emission of `a`.

I'm using reactivex/rxjs, but just a conceptual hint is more than enough. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `flatMap` over the `a$` Observable and return a new Observable that emits the first item that we get from `b$`.

*CAVEAT: `b$` needs to be a hot Observable. Please read up on hot/cold Observables if this term is unfamiliar: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables*

```
const firstBAfterA$ = a$.flatMap(x => {
  return b$.first();
});
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you!

Comment: What about `flatMapFirst`?

Comment: Depending on what behavior @BrandonHorst needs, `flatlMapFirst` may have also worked. The difference with `flatMapFirst` is that subsequent `b$.first()` Observables get dropped if a previous one hasn't completed yet.